# Mocking out Slack Web Client with Mock Class in Pytest

Tags: mocking, pytest, slack

I'm trying to write some pytests to test a function which uses an instance of the Slack SDK WebClient. I'm struggling to write a test which will mock out the client in the function, with a mock instance of the Mockerd Slack Web Client.

I'd like to be able to write tests for a valid email and an email that would raise an exception

```py
client = slack_sdk.WebClient(token="xxx")
def get_slack_id(user_email):
    try:
        user_info = client.users_lookupByEmail(email=user_email)
        return(user_info["user"]["id"])
    except Exception as e:
        return(e)
```

```py
############################
###--Mock Slack Api Error--###
##############################
class SlackApiError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, error_message):
        self.error_message = error_message

###############################
###--Mock Slack Web Client--###
###############################
class MockWebClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {
            firstuser@email.com: {"id": "ID123456789", "name": "First User"},
            seconduser@email.com: {"id": "ID901234567", "name": "Second User"},
        }
        self.messages = []

    def users_lookupByEmail(self, email):
        if email in self.users:
            return {"user": self.users[email]}
        else:
            print("error")
            raise SlackApiError(api_email_lookup_fail_message)

    def chat_postMessage(self, channel, text):
        for user in self.users.values():
            if user["id"] == channel:
                self.messages.append({"channel": channel, "text": text})
                return {"ok": True, "ts": "00000000.000000"} #TS = timestamp
            else:
                return {"ok": False, "error": "channel not found"}
```